# Universal Windows Unit Test App won't run tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2015, vs-unit-testing-framework

In Visual Studio 2015 Version 14.0.25422.01 Update 3 
I create an empty solution with no dependencies or nuget packages
I create a Unit Test App for windows universal
I create a Unit Test Project

I click "run all tests"
The unit test project runs properly
The Unit Test App for Windows Universal opens, and after a while hangs and closes. 
In the unit test explorer I click the "cancel" button but nothing happens.
In the Error List I see:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       DEP3000 : Attempts to stop the application failed. This may cause the deployment to fail. Exception from HRESULT: 0x92330047     UnitTestProject1
```

The tests worked 1 week ago, so I have no idea what broke everything or how to fix it. I already tried uninstalling VS and installing it again with no luck. The architecture of the test project is x86. Any Ideas?

Regards.

Comment: I have the same issue, I do not know if it has to be with the latest VS patch, or whatever. In my case I changed to Xunit to check but also fails, with the same HRESULT: 0x92330047

Comment: The only way to fix it is formating, if you happen to fix this bug please tell me, still not being able to run the tests.

Comment: Might be, because I uninstalled and deleted plenty of VS folders, reinstalling and the same error.

Comment: Me too, I removed nuget package folders but thought a clean VS install would fix it :(